# Where can I post IT jobs as an internal recruiter?

Tags: support, jobs

I'm new to Stack Overflow. I'm an internal recruiter. Can I post IT jobs here? If so, how and where?

Answer (score 23):

You can use Stack Overflow Careers: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products.